# glNamedBufferSubData Not updating between draws

Tags: c, opengl

I am having difficulties with rendering rectangles.
The rectangle vertices are being calculated using `gl_VertexID` using data from a Uniform Buffer Object.
However when updating the uniform buffer data between draw calls, the same elements seem to appear.

```
#version 440 
out vec3 r_uv;
out vec4 r_color;

layout (binding = 2, std140) uniform struct_uirect {
    vec2 pos;
    vec2 size;
    vec4 color;
    int uv;
} uirect;

void main(){
    vec2 verts[4] = vec2[4](
        vec2(0, 0),
        vec2(1, 0),
        vec2(0, 1),
        vec2(1, 1)
    );

    r_uv = vec3(verts[gl_VertexID], uirect.uv);
    r_color = uirect.color;

    vec2 vert = uirect.pos + verts[gl_VertexID] * uirect.size;    
    vert = vert * 2 - 1;

    gl_Position = vec4(vert, 0.0, 1.0);
 }

#version 440 
out vec4 color;
in vec3 r_uv;
in vec4 r_color;
layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler2DArray voxel_atlas;
void main(){
    color = texture(voxel_atlas, r_uv) * r_color;
}
```

Because of order dependence every element is being drawn separately, using the following recursive function.

```
void UI_Tag_Render(Tag* tag, int x, int y, int w, int h){
    glViewport(x, y, w, h);
    glNamedBufferSubData(binding_points[2], 0, sizeof(Tag), tag);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    if(tag->child)
        UI_Tag_Render(
            tag->child, 
            x + w * tag->pos[0], 
            y + h * tag->pos[1], 
            w * tag->size[0], 
            h * tag->size[1]
        );

    if(tag->sibling)
        UI_Tag_Render(tag->sibling, x, y, w, h);
}
```

This results in getting same elements that progressively get smaller (due to `glViewport` call).
The uniform buffer object is created empty (with the `sizeof(Tag)` size), and once the `glNamedBufferSubData` is called, it's data doesn't seem to update.

The same way of handling ubo's is used in a different shader that seems to handle correctly (but that one draws directly to screen, and has input vertices)

Comment: FYI: this code is very bad from a performance standpoint. Viewport changes should not be done for *every* UI element; just do the vertex offsetting yourself. You should not modify buffer data that is currently in use by a rendering command like that. You should instead build an array of vertices that represent the vertices of the rectangles (doing the viewport transform on the CPU), and render them all in one draw call with the same viewport.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'd really love it if you could recommend a good resource for solving some of these problems. The glViewport manages clipping for me. I don't quite understand "modify data currently in use" isn't a draw call blocking untill rendered? One draw call is unfortunately not a option due to transparency (order dependent) rendering.

Comment: "*isn't a draw call blocking untill rendered?*" [No. Fortunately.](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Synchronization#Asynchronous_action) "*One draw call is unfortunately not a option due to transparency (order dependent) rendering.*" The [order in which primitives are rendered is well-defined](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive_Assembly#Primitive_order). As long as you put them in the buffer in the right order, you'll get the blending you desire.

Comment: Are you sure the buffer ID is 2? How do you know the buffer ID is 2?

Comment: @user253751 Sorry, that was an error from my part while editing the code to not use my own functions. I've edited the post.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you alot, those two links solve so many of the design problems I've got in my source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does appear to be a synchronization issue. (I'm not sure whether this is driver related or valid in the opengl standard)

Adding a `glFinish()` call after the draw call, will cause the UBO to be updated correctly.

Thanks to @NicolBolas for pointing out that draw calls are indeed asynchronous.